# How to Call Websocket from HTML Client?

Tags: javascript, html, wcf, websocket

I have written one wcf Service with netHttpBinding binding and hosted in II8(windows server 2012).The interfaces are like the bellow.

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IDuplexCallbackContract))]
public interface IHelloWebSocket
{
   [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")] 
   void SayHelloDuplexReceive(string name);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IDuplexCallbackContract
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")] 
    void SayingHelloSend(string message);
}
```

now I have the service class implementation like the bellow..

```
 [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
public class HelloWebSocket : IHelloWebSocket
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Call back instance called from service to client.
    /// </summary>
    IDuplexCallbackContract _callback = null;

    public HelloWebSocket()
    {
        _callback =
            OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IDuplexCallbackContract>();
    }

    public void SayHelloDuplexReceive(string name)
    {
        _callback.SayingHelloSend("Hello " + name + " by WebSockets");

        //return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

and the web config like the bellow..

```
<system.serviceModel>
     <services>
       <service name="WebSocketUndersranding.HelloWebSocket">
          <endpoint address=""
            binding="netHttpBinding"
            contract="WebSocketUndersranding.IHelloWebSocket"/>
     </service>
    </services>
     <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
              <behavior name="">
                  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                 <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
             </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
           multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   </system.serviceModel>
```

Now How Can I call the Service from the HTML5 client.??

My Service URL is a link

I am trying to write the client 
    var websocket = new WebSocket(uri);
but what should I put in the "uri" to call the service.I am not able to get..???

Thanks,
Arijit

Comment: I have posted an answer on the similar topic here:
[wcf self hosted websocket service with javascript client][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239953/wcf-self-hosted-websocket-service-with-javascript-client/26527058#26527058

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this articles as example to start from:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/338789/What-s-new-in-WCF-4-5-WebSocket-support-Part-1-of
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/341413/What-s-new-in-WCF-4-5-WebSocket-support-Part-2-of