# WCF self-hosted WebSocket Service with Javascript client

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf, websocket, self-hosting

I have this WCF self-hosted WebSocket service code:

**Main:**

```
//Create a URI to serve as the base address
Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://192.168.1.95:8080/service");
//Create ServiceHost
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WebSocketService), httpUrl);            
//Add a service endpoint
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWebSocket), new NetHttpBinding(), "");
//Enable metadata exchange
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
//Start the Service
host.Open();

Console.WriteLine("Service is host at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Host is running... Press <Enter> key to stop");
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Interface:**

```
namespace IWebSocketHostTest
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IWebSocketCallBack
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Send(int num);
    }

    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IWebSocketCallBack))]
    public interface IWebSocket
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void StartSend();
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
namespace IWebSocketHostTest
{

class WebSocketService : IWebSocket
{
    Timer timer = null;

    List<IWebSocketCallBack> callbackClientList = null;        

    public WebSocketService()
    {
        callbackClientList = new List<IWebSocketCallBack>();

        timer = new Timer(3000);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(sendNumber);
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void StartSend()
    {
        sender.addClient(OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IWebSocketCallBack>());            
    }

    private void sendNumber(Object o, ElapsedEventArgs eea)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        var random = new Random();
        int randomNum = random.Next(100);
        foreach (IWebSocketCallBack callback in callbackClientList)
        {
            callback.Send(randomNum);
        }

        timer.Interval = random.Next(1000, 10000);
        timer.Start();
    }

}
}
```

This works perfect if i add a reference of this service in another .NET application.
But, what i need is to consume this service from an HTML+Javascript application, and i´m realy lost in how to do that. I couldn´t find a good example or tutorial with a Javascript client consuming a self-hosted WCF WebSocket service.
All the Javascript WebSocket code that i could find seems to be very simple, but i couldn´t make it work.

Here is my short JavaScript client test:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.95:8080/service");
            ws.onopen = function () {
                console.log("WEBSOCKET CONNECTED");
            };
```

it returns "WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 400, Bad Request" testing it with Fiddler.

What am i missing? Could you please give me some doc links to get more information or a code example?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

**Now i´ve tried using the "Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSocket" library** to try to make it work.

But, first, i don´t know if it´s still maintained by Microsoft or if it is deprecated, because i couldn´t find any information at MSDN and there is few info at internet.
And second, the "Open()" method of the "WebSocketHost" class is not found, so i don´t know how to make the server run...

Here is my code, i´ve taken it from a [question](http://forums.asp.net/t/1732788.aspx?Problem%20with%20self%20hosted%20WCF%20WebSocket) at the ASP.NET forum.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets;

namespace WebSocketTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebSocketHost<EchoService>(new Uri("ws://localhost:8080/echo"));
        host.AddWebSocketEndpoint();
        host.Open();

        Console.Read();

        host.Close();
    }
}

class EchoService : WebSocketService
{

    public override void OnOpen()
    {
        base.OnOpen();
        Console.WriteLine("WebSocket opened.");
    }

    public override void OnMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Echoing to client:");
        Console.WriteLine(message);

        this.Send(message);
    }

    protected override void OnClose()
    {
        base.OnClose();
        Console.WriteLine("WebSocket closed.");
    }

    protected override void OnError()
    {
        base.OnError();
        Console.WriteLine("WebSocket error occured.");
    }
}
}
```

But, like i said before, the "host.Open()" method is not found, so i don´t know if i´m missing some reference or what, because i couldn´t find info about the WebSocketHost class... Any help?

Comment: Take a look on this http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WCF-WebSocket-Listener-3adf403d

Comment: May I ask why you want to use WCF for a WebSocket server? just curious... :)

Comment: Because my idea is to use Named Pipes for internal communication when the client is in the same machine as the server, and  websockets when the client is outside (need full-duplex), but if there is a better option i´m listening. BTW i have SignalR in mind, but i haven´t had time to read enought docs and i haven´t made any test yet.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 8.1
And thanks for the link above, it´s a good example for me, but the problem is that in my Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets (0.2.3 version) library there is NO "Open()" method for "WebSocketHost"; so the example turns useless...

Comment: Sorry about that. If you do not get to make it work, you can take a look at my WebSocket connector: http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/ , at least it will work :D. Anyway, if you make that Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets work, please update this post with the answer since it is interesting.

Answer (score 31):

After spending a day with the same task I finally got working solution. Hope it will help someone in the future.

Client JS script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>WebSocket Chat</title>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ws;
    $().ready(function ()
    {
        $("#btnConnect").click(function ()
        {
            $("#spanStatus").text("connecting");

            ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/hello");

            ws.onopen = function ()
            {
                $("#spanStatus").text("connected");
            };
            ws.onmessage = function (evt)
            {
                $("#spanStatus").text(evt.data);
            };
            ws.onerror = function (evt)
            {
                $("#spanStatus").text(evt.message);
            };
            ws.onclose = function ()
            {
                $("#spanStatus").text("disconnected");
            };
        });
        $("#btnSend").click(function ()
        {
            if (ws.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN)
            {
                var res = ws.send($("#textInput").val());
            }
            else
            {
                $("#spanStatus").text("Connection is closed");
            }
        });
        $("#btnDisconnect").click(function ()
        {
            ws.close();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Connect" id="btnConnect" />
<input type="button" value="Disconnect" id="btnDisconnect" /><br />
<input type="text" id="textInput" />
<input type="button" value="Send" id="btnSend" /><br />
<span id="spanStatus">(display)</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Self hosted server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebSocketsServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/hello");

            // Create the ServiceHost.
            using(ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WebSocketsServer), baseAddress))
            {
                // Enable metadata publishing.
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
                binding.Elements.Add(new ByteStreamMessageEncodingBindingElement());
                HttpTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
                //transport.WebSocketSettings = new WebSocketTransportSettings();
                transport.WebSocketSettings.TransportUsage = WebSocketTransportUsage.Always;
                transport.WebSocketSettings.CreateNotificationOnConnection = true;
                binding.Elements.Add(transport);

                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWebSocketsServer), binding, "");

                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
                Console.ReadLine();

                // Close the ServiceHost.
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IProgressContext))]
    public interface IWebSocketsServer
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
        void SendMessageToServer(Message msg);
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    interface IProgressContext
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
        void ReportProgress(Message msg);
    }

    public class WebSocketsServer: IWebSocketsServer
    {
        public void SendMessageToServer(Message msg)
        {
            var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IProgressContext>();
            if(msg.IsEmpty || ((IChannel)callback).State != CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                return;
            }

            byte[] body = msg.GetBody<byte[]>();
            string msgTextFromClient = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

            string msgTextToClient = string.Format(
                "Got message {0} at {1}",
                msgTextFromClient,
                DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

            callback.ReportProgress(CreateMessage(msgTextToClient));
        }

        private Message CreateMessage(string msgText)
        {
            Message msg = ByteStreamMessage.CreateMessage(
                new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msgText)));

            msg.Properties["WebSocketMessageProperty"] =
                new WebSocketMessageProperty
                {
                    MessageType = WebSocketMessageType.Text
                };

            return msg;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As of .net 4.5 new way of writing server side have emerged. The benefits are cleaner code and possibility to support secure web sockets (WSS) over https.

```
public class WebSocketsServer
{
    #region Fields

    private static CancellationTokenSource m_cancellation;
    private static HttpListener m_listener;

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private static async Task AcceptWebSocketClientsAsync(HttpListener server, CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var hc = await server.GetContextAsync();
            if (!hc.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                hc.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                hc.Response.Close();
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                var ws = await hc.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (ws != null)
                {
                    Task.Run(() => HandleConnectionAsync(ws.WebSocket, token));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception aex)
            {
                // Log error here
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task HandleConnectionAsync(WebSocket ws, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        try
        {
                while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open && !cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    String messageString = await ReadString(ws).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    var strReply = "OK"; // Process messageString and get your reply here;

                    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strReply);
                    var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);
                    await ws.SendAsync(segment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }

                await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Done", CancellationToken.None);
        }
        catch (Exception aex)
        {
            // Log error

            try
            {
                await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.InternalServerError, "Done", CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            ws.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private static async Task<String> ReadString(WebSocket ws)
    {
        ArraySegment<Byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new Byte[8192]);

        WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            do
            {
                result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
            }
            while (!result.EndOfMessage);

            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public static void Start(string uri)
    {
        m_listener = new HttpListener();
        m_listener.Prefixes.Add(uri);
        m_listener.Start();

        m_cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Run(() => AcceptWebSocketClientsAsync(m_listener, m_cancellation.Token));
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        if(m_listener != null && m_cancellation != null)
        {
            try
            {
                m_cancellation.Cancel();

                m_listener.Stop();

                m_listener = null;
                m_cancellation = null;
            }
            catch
            {
                // Log error
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Sweet. Small, easy, and quick to implement. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect!. But I have a question. How can change Authentication settings to Windows Authentication. I am connecting to WebSocket server from MyWebSite. MyWebsite's authentication mode is Windows. But I cant connect to websocket when I changed the tranport.AuthenticationSchema = AuthenticationSchema.NTLM . Help Pls

Comment: I don't think its possible. For more info on authentication you can check this question for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593948/websocket-authentication-security