# Self-hosted websocket service multi OperationContract?

Tags: websocket

First, sorry for my english...

I have a problem , I searched but I didnt found any answer.

I found a answer code at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239953/wcf-self-hosted-websocket-service-with-javascript-client?answertab=votes#tab-top)

This code working fine..

WebSocket Service and Server :

```
// Self-hosted Server start at http://localhost:8080/hello
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebSocketsServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/hello");

            // Create the ServiceHost.
            using(ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WebSocketsServer), baseAddress))
            {
                // Enable metadata publishing.
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
                binding.Elements.Add(new ByteStreamMessageEncodingBindingElement());
                HttpTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
                //transport.WebSocketSettings = new WebSocketTransportSettings();
                transport.WebSocketSettings.TransportUsage = WebSocketTransportUsage.Always;
                transport.WebSocketSettings.CreateNotificationOnConnection = true;
                binding.Elements.Add(transport);

                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWebSocketsServer), binding, "");

                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
                Console.ReadLine();

                // Close the ServiceHost.
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IProgressContext))]
    public interface IWebSocketsServer
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
        void SendMessageToServer(Message msg);
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    interface IProgressContext
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
        void ReportProgress(Message msg);
    }

    public class WebSocketsServer: IWebSocketsServer
    {
        public void SendMessageToServer(Message msg)
        {
            var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IProgressContext>();
            if(msg.IsEmpty || ((IChannel)callback).State != CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                return;
            }

            byte[] body = msg.GetBody<byte[]>();
            string msgTextFromClient = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

            string msgTextToClient = string.Format(
                "Got message {0} at {1}",
                msgTextFromClient,
                DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

            callback.ReportProgress(CreateMessage(msgTextToClient));
        }

        private Message CreateMessage(string msgText)
        {
            Message msg = ByteStreamMessage.CreateMessage(
                new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msgText)));

            msg.Properties["WebSocketMessageProperty"] =
                new WebSocketMessageProperty
                {
                    MessageType = WebSocketMessageType.Text
                };

            return msg;
        }
    }
}
```

and Client Html Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>WebSocket Chat</title>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ws;
    $().ready(function ()
    {
        $("#btnConnect").click(function ()
        {
            $("#spanStatus").text("connecting");

            ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/hello");

            ws.onopen = function ()
            {
                $("#spanStatus").text("connected");
            };
            ws.onmessage = function (evt)
            {
                $("#spanStatus").text(evt.data);
            };
            ws.onerror = function (evt)
            {
                $("#spanStatus").text(evt.message);
            };
            ws.onclose = function ()
            {
                $("#spanStatus").text("disconnected");
            };
        });
        $("#btnSend").click(function ()
        {
            if (ws.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN)
            {
                var res = ws.send($("#textInput").val());
            }
            else
            {
                $("#spanStatus").text("Connection is closed");
            }
        });
        $("#btnDisconnect").click(function ()
        {
            ws.close();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Connect" id="btnConnect" />
<input type="button" value="Disconnect" id="btnDisconnect" /><br />
<input type="text" id="textInput" />
<input type="button" value="Send" id="btnSend" /><br />
<span id="spanStatus">(display)</span>
</body>
</html>
```

this is working great!.. but.. :)

IWebSocketsServer has one method and Action="*" parameter in OperationContract Property.

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IProgressContext))]
public interface IWebSocketsServer
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
    void SendMessageToServer(Message msg);
}
```

Its not working when I removed Action="*" parameter.

But I want to add new methods like SendMessageToServer.

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IProgressContext))]
public interface IWebSocketsServer
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
    void SendMessageToServer(Message msg);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
    void DifferentMethod(string msg);
}
```

but when Self-hosted server starting, this code throwing error **"A ServiceContract has more the one operation with an Action of "*".  A ServiceContract can have at most one operation an Action = "*"."**

I tried to change values of Action Parameters like "Send", "Test". Server started without problem. 
But client not connecting to "ws://localhost:8080/hello"...

I want to call methods like

```
            ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Send");

            ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Test");
```

I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two operation contracts that point to "*". This is producing the error message that you are getting. 
See: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.action(v=vs.110).aspx

The two calls you have specified would create two WebSocket connections one for each of the endpoints if you had services at those endpoints.

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Send");
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Test");
```

I think what you need is a WebSocket connection and then use the ws.Send(message) to send a message to the WebSocket server.  If you use a sub-protocol for the messages you may get the flexibility you need.

Hope that helps you move forward with WebSockets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I sent json data in message and parsed in service. Json Data contains "HandlerType" , "ActionType". My Socket service invoking to classes :)